# reledmac footnote style in paracol environment

Tags: footnotes, two-column, reledmac, paracol

Is there anyway to use a predefined reledmac standard of two-column footnote inside a paracol environment. While the two-column paracol does provide its own two-column footnote (which works fine), I have to use a journal pre-defined reledmac footnote style exclusively. What I need is for paracol footnote to be disabled and all footnotes to follow the pre-set reledmac style (thereby, avoiding the four-columned footnote style seen below).

NOTE: I realise I can take the \footnoteAtexts out of the paracol environment and thereby get the desired two-column footnote, but as the paracol text I am working with spans several pages (and can't be broken up), putting the footnoteAtexts outside the paracol environment causes the footnotes to be typset a whole lot later from where the footnoteAmarks appear. Many thanks.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage[nocritical,
    noend,
    series={A}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{setspace}
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\beforenotesX{2em plus 1.5em minus 1.5em} 


\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
test\footnoteAmark[1]\bigskip

\lipsum[3]\bigskip

test2\footnoteAmark[2]\bigskip

\switchcolumn
\lipsum[5]

\footnoteAtext[1]{{\lipsum[2]}}
\footnoteAtext[2]{{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Suffice it so say that reledmax and prarcol are not compatible.  If you can emulate reledmac's stylistic peculiarites using some other package or with a custom \vbox, do so.

Answer (score 0):

Not an solution, but an even more bewildering experiment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage[nocritical,
    noend,
    series={A}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{setspace}
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\beforenotesX{2em plus 1.5em minus 1.5em} 

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
test\footnoteAmark[1]\bigskip

\lipsum[3]\bigskip

test2\footnoteAmark[2]\bigskip

\switchcolumn
\lipsum[5]
\footnoteAtext[1]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\lipsum[2]}}
\footnoteAtext[2]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```